# Docker different CMD based on ENV

Tags: docker

I want run a different command in the same image, based on an ENV variable, eg.:

```
FROM node:12-slim

ENV MODE server
# ENV MODE worker

# workdir
RUN mkdir -p /opt/backend
WORKDIR /opt/backend
COPY . /opt/backend

# Install node modules
RUN npm install --production --no-audit

EXPOSE 3000


RUN if [ "server" = "$MODE" ] ; then \
    CMD [ "node", "./build/server.js"]; \
  else \
    CMD [ "node", "./build/worker.js"]; \
fi
```

This example didn't works, how fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in entry point instead of `CMD`.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "server" = "${MODE} ]; then
  # check the correct path
  echo "application starting with server mode"
  node ./build/server.js
else 
  node ./build/worker.js 
fi
```

Dockerfile will look like

```
FROM node:12-slim

ENV MODE server
RUN mkdir -p /opt/backend
WORKDIR /opt/backend
COPY . /opt/backend
# Install node modules
RUN npm install --production --no-audit
EXPOSE 3000
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
entrypoint ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: Thanks... another idea is `CMD [ "node", "./build/$MODE.js"]` ... do you think it's okay?

Comment: That form will try to literally run a script named `$MODE.js` without expanding it.  If you use the string form `CMD node "./build/$MODE.js"` then Docker will wrap it in `sh -c`, which will expand the variable for you.

Comment: Shell expansion not work in CMD, you need mention shell like sh - c "nodejs..", on cell phone so sorry for the typos

Answer (score 2):

When you launch the container, you can specify the command, and that will override the `CMD` in the Dockerfile.

For example, let's say you think the container is "usually" the server, so you write

```
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "./build/server.js"]
```

Now you can build and run that container, but run a second container with a different command.

```
docker build -t my-node-app .
docker run -d --name server \
  -p 3000:3000
  my-node-app
  # with its default command
docker run -d --name worker \
  my-node-app \
  node ./build/worker.js
```

You can do something similar specifying a `command:` in a `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a shell script inside your container which contains your

```
if ….
    ….. \
  else \
    …..  \
fi
```

and run it